# Product of elements of scipy sparse matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I can find sum of all (non-zero) elements in scipy sparse matrix by `mat.sum()`, but how can I find their product? There's no `mat.prod()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any plugin that is named as "infinite posts scroll" or "jetpack" or any thing similar delete it.